# Javascript only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My Javascript pulls from an API array a list of results. For some reason it works perfectly in Chrome but no other browser. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Full webpage is http://that-gift.co.uk, code below.

```
var dataCallback = function(data) {


  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var d = data[i];
    for (var k in d.data) {
        if (k == 'price'){
          price = d.data[k];

        }
        if (k == 'name'){
          name = d.data[k];
    if(name.length > 10) name = name.substring(0,30) + "...";

        }
        if (k == 'link'){
          link = d.data[k];

        }
        if (k == 'image'){
          image = d.data[k];

        }
    }
        document.write("<div class='result'><a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'><img src='" + image + "'><div class='resultname'>" + name + "</div><span class='prices'>&#163;"+ price + "</span></a></div>");
      }
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors? something?

Answer (score 2):

Your Javascript works. The issue is that your line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

is missing a closing tag. Try one of the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<!-- or -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
```

Chrome is forgiving you and inferring the closing tag, but the other browsers are not, so ALL the `<script>` elements that follow are considered to be "within" the `<link>` element, and so are being removed/ignored.